# PCRE2 (PHP>=7.3) Positive Lookbehind Regex to search for strings separated by ","

Tags: javascript, php, regex, pcre, pcre2

I have this string:

```
'newProductsInfo: [[1] - $2 dollars,[2] New Product,[3] Hello,[4]Same, [5]Value]'
```

The word `'newProductsInfo'`, and a space `' '` always precede the array of strings. I want to be able to return

```
[1] - $2 dollars

[2] New Product

[3] Hello

[4]Same, [5]Value //should be returned since the comma is followed by a space ' '
```

in the [Regex101 site](https://regex101.com/).

Currently, using `(?<=newProductsInfo: \[)[^,\]]+` only returns `[1`.

[image]

Edit: added possible return types in bubble plugin creator:

[image]

Comment: _"I have this string"_ - The first thing to do is usually to figure out in what format the string is. I don't recognize it. Where does this string come from? Most properly specified formats already have parsers so you don't have to go regex on the string. It looks like a complicated format so you will _most probably_ parse it erroneously if you try it with regex - if not with the data you see Today, then with something that pops up Tomorrow.

Comment: @TedLyngmo I'm using it inside a [website builder](https://bubble.io), and in there I'm only allowed to return texts or a list of texts. aside from the object I have in my question, I'm also returning various other objects. Then again, I can only return it as a text. Limitations of the app made me use regex for recognizing patterns.

Comment: May I suggest returning text formatted as JSON? You then have a very well defined format and support in most (all?) languages to parse it properly.

Comment: using JSON only displays something like [object Object] so it was useless for me.

Comment: Then you used it wrong. You need to build the JSON object and convert it to a string before returning it. Do the opposite on the receiving side.

Comment: Is this a PHP problem, or a JS problem?

Comment: @NicoHaase its a php problem

Comment: @NicoHaase I need to make it work [here](https://regex101.com/r/dHZWQ8/1)

Comment: @ProsyArceno How much time did you spend on trying to get JSON working? Did you give up when you noticed that your JSON object appeared as `[object Object]`? If you had just spent a few minutes extra there, I'm pretty sure you'd figure out how to make it appear as a fully parseable string - and all this regexing of your own format would be a non-issue.

Comment: If this is a PHP problem, please share the code invovled

Comment: @TedLyngmo, I'm new to the web builder and newer to its plugin creator. But I am limited to the return of the plugin creator, see edit above

Comment: It looks like they've tried to make it simple to juggle JSON objects back and forth. I suggest spending some time investigating that a bit more. Perhaps ask about how to do it properly in one of their own user forums (if they have any)

Comment: @TedLyngmo It's not so much a problem in the app but a problem in the return of the API I'm using. Mapping made it problematic because what supposedly should be returned as an array is being returned as a dictionary. What I'm currently doing is a workaround, which because of my limited knowledge of the app, may not be the most optimised. See [here](https://forum.bubble.io/t/extracting-return-of-a-plugin-and-saving-to-database/243599/3). I've gone past extracting the ids months ago. Now, I wanna get the names instead, so here I am.

Comment: @ProsyArceno The JSON you showed in that question is far from valid JSON, so I'd take their answer with a grain of salt. What if you asked the same question, but with valid JSON?

Comment: @TedLyngmo that is the actual represented return from the API I'm currently using. See last edit a result from a call I made.

Comment: Your latest addition to the question contains pictures though. It's pretty hard to validate those. Put the data _as-is_ in the question as text and I'll give it a go.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your pattern (was tagged JavaScript) only matches `[1` because the negated character class `[^,\]]+` can not cross matching a comma or `]`

If you want the matches only, you can assert `newProductsInfo:`  to the left followed by any character

Start the match with digits between square brackets up until either the next occurrence preceded by a comma, or the end of the string.

Using a lookbehind assertion (see the [support](https://caniuse.com/js-regexp-lookbehind)) for it:

```
(?<=newProductsInfo: .*?)\[\d+].*?(?=,\[\d+]|$)
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/uMBBLa/1)

**Edit**

If you want to use PHP:

```
(?:newProductsInfo: \[|\G(?!^)),?\K[^,\n]+(?>,\h+[^,\n]+)*
```

**Explanation**

- `(?:` Non capture group for the alternatives

  - `newProductsInfo: \[` Match `newProductsInfo: [`
  - `|` Or
  - `\G(?!^)` Assert the current position at the end of the previous match, not at the start
- `)` Close the non capture group
- `,?\K` Match an optional comma and forget what is matched so far
- `[^,\n]+`
- `(?>,\h+[^,\n]+)*` Optionally repeat matching a comma, 1+ spaces and 1+ chars other than `,` or newline

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/sQ6rbN/1)

Comment: I don't know why we're having different [results](https://regex101.com/r/6pex53/1).

Comment: @ProsyArceno you should select Javascript as the flavor https://regex101.com/r/ADKUI3/1

Comment: This answer will only work on versions of JavaScript which support lookbehinds.  On some browsers, lookbehinds would not be supported.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen That is correct, although the OP is using a lookbehind assertion

Comment: Is there a way to do this on the default PCRE2 (PHP>=7.3)? I'm using bubble and I wasn't sure if JS was used

Comment: @ProsyArceno Why did you tag Javascript?

Comment: @ProsyArceno I have added a pattern that you can use with PHP .

Comment: The php version is not working on PCRE2 (PHP>=7.3). Like [here](https://regex101.com/r/dHZWQ8/1).

Comment: I might have used a wrong sample case because there are cases with which a string does not begin with a '[number]'

Comment: @ProsyArceno Try it like this `(?:newProductsInfo: |\G(?!^)).*?\K\[[^][]*].*?(?=,\[[^][]*]|$)`  See https://regex101.com/r/cffvF7/1

Comment: this worked somehow, but there should be four returns as opposed to just two.

Comment: @ProsyArceno which 4? there are 2 parts with square brackets right?

Comment: no, i just want the values separated by a comma (,), and preceded by a ‘newProductsInfo: [’ and ended with ‘]’. basically all csv inside the array.

Comment: @ProsyArceno In that case `(?:newProductsInfo: \[|\G(?!^)),?\K[^,\n]+(?>,\h+[^,\n]+)*` https://regex101.com/r/sQ6rbN/1

Comment: this is perfect. worked nicely

Comment: My version with a style from outerspace: https://regex101.com/r/EfwuEC/1

Comment: @CasimiretHippolyte Awesome, like a real pro ;-) Some food for thought on this Friday evening. I remember seeing you use a marker before, but I have to read into this again.

Comment: Thanks! Unfortunately, you can't see the markers with regex101, but `preg_match*` functions show them in the result array.

Comment: @CasimiretHippolyte Cool! I did not know that either about the preg_match functions.

Answer (score 1):

Here is one approach using `match()`:

```js
var input = 'newProductsInfo: [[1] - $2 dollars,[2] New Product,[3] Hello,[4]Same, [5]Value]';
var matches = input.replace(/^.*?\[(?=\[\d+\])|\]$/g, "")
                   .split(/,(?=\[\d+\])/);
console.log(matches);
```

The call to `replace()` strips off the leading/trailing `[` and `]`.  The call to `split()` splits the input string at every comma which is followed by a numbered bracket term such as `[2]`.